# Want to Filter a list of items(li) for a partial match rather than exact(phrase) match using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filter

consider this following function:

```
//This piece of code works for exact word match but I want something more of a partial match.
    function filterItems(ev) {
        let text = ev.target.value.toLowerCase();
        let items = item_list.getElmentsByTagName("li");
        Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
         let item_name = item.firstChild.textContent;
         if(item_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
            item.style.display = "block";
         } else {
            item.style.display = "none";
         }
      })
    }
```

Here is what I'm trying to do instead, something like using filter on search phrase itself

```
function filterItems(ev) {
     let text = ev.target.value.toLowerCase();
     let items = item_list.getElmentsByTagName("li");
     Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
        let item_name = item.firstChild.textContent;
        if(item_name.toLowerCase().split("").filter(ch => ch.indexOf(text) !== -1)) {
                item.style.display = "block";
             } else {
                item.style.display = "none";
             }
          })
        }
```

Is it anywhere near what I'm trying to do, it doesn't seem to be responding to this piece of code on browser!!

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. How is `text` supposed to be a part of `ch` - a _character_? Could you provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @raina77ow yeah, "ch" is supposed to be a part of "text" if it exist of course.

For example: 

- list 01
- list 02

and i want to have a partial match for search phrase such as "lst1" or "ls" or "01" or "02" rather than "list 01" or "list 02" which are exact search phrase match!!

hope this make sense!! Thanks for looking into this,  I really appreciate this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can leverage regular expression here with i flag which will ignore case, to use dynamic regular rexpression here we are using constructor.

```
function filterItems(ev) {
 const regExp = new RegExp(`[${ev.target.value}]`, 'i');
 let items = item_list.getElmentsByTagName("li");
 Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
    let item_name = item.firstChild.textContent;
    if(regExp.test(item_name)) {
            item.style.display = "block";
         } else {
            item.style.display = "none";
         }
      })
    }
```

if you want to display all items when search box is empty then it should be

```
      function filterItems(ev) {
    // using regex
    let regExp = new RegExp(`[${ev.target.value}]`, 'i');
    // converting text to lowerCase
    // let text = ev.target.value.toLowerCase();
    // get ul li elemnts
    let items = item_list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    // Convert it to an array
    Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
      let item_name = item.firstChild.textContent;
      if (!ev.target.value || regExp.test(item_name)) {
        item.style.display = "inline-block";
      } else {
        item.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much for looking into this, I really appreciate this RegExp approach for this. Here is what I have got so far https://codepen.io/bappyasif/pen/BazNgQm
would you mind looking into it and see why isn't it behaving as expected!!

Comment: I am looking into code pen, i belive you want to filter out the items which does not have any character in search box right?

Comment: your css for true condition should be item.style.display = "inline-block"; instead item.style.display = "block-inline"; with this change its doing what you would expect.

Comment: if you use the alternate code I have added in which css is corrected and taken scenario where you may want to list all items when search box is empty.

Comment: Awesome Rajanikant, thank you very much :)
I should have cracked that myself but still I really appreciate your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment, I believe this achieves the behaviour you are after.
My `this.target` is your `text` variable. You could call the following `doesFilterMatchTarget()` inside your forEach item loop.

I have added inline comments for further explanation.

```
  function doesFilterMatchTarget(filter) {
    filter = filter.toLowerCase();

    if (filter.length === -1) { //empty state should not match
      return false;
    }

    let currentTarget = this.target; //initialise to your starting target e.g. 'list 01'

    for (let i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
      //call our helper function below to check and update our target word
      currentTarget = this.updateTargetWord(currentTarget, filter[i]);
      if (currentTarget === null) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true; //we have looped through every letter and they were all found in a correct location
  }


  function updateTargetWord(currentTarget, letterToSearchFor) {
    let index = currentTarget.search(letterToSearchFor);
    if (index === -1) {
      return null; //the letter was not in the target
    }

    // then we want to return the remainder of this target string from the next character to the end of the string
    return currentTarget.substring(index + 1, currentTarget.length);
  }
```

Note: this may be able to be optimised, but it seems to return what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you so much for looking into this, no idea why my earlier comment got vanished somehow!! Anyways this is where it is now after using your provided code https://codepen.io/bappyasif/pen/xxOGNvo could you please have a look at it and see it for yourself where it needs more editing!! thanks again